# Segmentation fault in malloc while using linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, malloc

The program reads from a file, stores the required data in some variables then push it to a stack. This is a small part of the input file, the file contains this data repeated several times( value of variables changed in each chunk of data ).

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Timestamp (Wed Mar 29 20:44:08 2017) 
[1] Received msg from node <00116 / fc:c2:3d:00:00:10:ab:35> 
RSSI -6 dBm / LQI 22
+[Node_Voltage]  <2.963000 Volts> 
+[P_MS5637]      <896 mbar> 
+[NTC_THERM (Murata NXFT15XH103)]    <27.755314 deg C> 
+[Temp_LM75B]    <27.620001 Deg C> 
+[RH_CC2D33S]    <33.000000 %> 
+[Temp_CC2D33S]  <27.000000 Deg C>
```

The stored data is pushed to a stack where the segmentation fault is occurring. The program is able to store only one stack after that the fault occurs.

```
void create(stack **head){
    *head=NULL;
}

void copy_string(char arr[],char arr2[]){
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(arr2);i++){
        arr[i] = arr2[i];
    }
}

stack demo;          
stack *tracker;

// **head is used since this is an ADT, i've not pasted the code in source file here 

void push(stack **head,char date[],char time[],char month[],char year[],float pressure,float temprature1,float temprature2,float rel_humid,float node_voltage){
    stack *temp = malloc(sizeof(demo));   

    temp->pressure = pressure;
    temp->temprature1 = temprature1;
    temp->temprature2 = temprature2;
    temp->rel_humid = rel_humid;
    temp->node_voltage = node_voltage;

    printf("Inside push function\n");

    copy_string(temp->date, date);
    copy_string(temp->time, time);
    copy_string(temp->month, month);
    copy_string(temp->year, year);


    if(*head==NULL){
        temp->next = NULL;
        *head = temp;
        tracker = temp;
    }
    else{
        tracker->next = temp;
        tracker = tracker->next;
        tracker->next = NULL;
    }

    free(temp);     //on removing this, program runs infinitely instead of giving segmentation fault

    printf("%s %s %f %f ",tracker->date,tracker->year,tracker->pressure,tracker->node_voltage);
}
```

Using gdb( GNU Debugger ) i got this error message -

```
Inside push function

29 2017) 896.000000 2.963000 Done!!

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x11f1) at malloc.c:2949
2949    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

SOLVED : The reason for the whole problem was free(temp), it needed to be removed from the above code and also in the main file, file pointer was getting closed by mistake after running the code once so infinite loop was running while taking input again.

Comment: `*head==NULL;` --> `*head=NULL;`

Comment: When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's important to not forget the ***complete*** part. Where's the `main` function? How do you use these functions you show? What do you pass them? What is `stack`? A `create` function that doesn't really *create* anything? Why do you have your own `copy_string` instead of the standard `strcpy`? And when you catch a crash in a debugger, always check the call stack (using the `bt` command in GDB) so you know where in *your* code it happens.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i corrected that but still getting the same error

Comment: Remove `free(temp);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is just a part of a file added as header in my other file which is the main file, the code of which i've not pasted

Comment: @BLUEPIXY on removing free(temp) the program keeps on running infinitely, no fault occurs.

Comment: _program keeps on running infinitely_ :That is probably due to another part.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY should i paste the code of other part?

Comment: The problem with `free(temp)` is that you free the memory you just allocated for a node you added to your stack. When you link the node into the list, you only link to the memory allocated by `malloc`, you do not create a new `stack` structure by that. When you call `free(temp)` you leave the list with a stray pointer to unallocated memory, leading to *undefined behavior* when you attempt to access that memory. If this is the reason for the crash we can only speculate on though.

Comment: @Masquerade I do not want to see it, but it is necessary for people other than you to know the cause of the infinite loop.

Comment: What's the problem with free(temp) when i removed it and ran the program with gdb i got this output -- Inside push function

29 2017) 896.000000 2.963000 Done!!^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7a69884 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=s@entry=0x603010, format=0x40146d "%s", 
    argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffd4a8, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:279
279 vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: As for the infinite loop that might be a completely different problem and if so should warrant a new question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i've pasted the error messaget of gdb when i broke that loop with Ctrl + c in gdb

Comment: And again, please [learn how to *use* GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)! How to see the function call stack with [the `bt` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html#Backtrace).

Comment: @Masquerade Alternative: debug from within your IDE. These offer a GUI for gdb, which makes life a little easier, showing the call stack immediately on a break.

Comment: To answer this question fully, we need: 1. the definition of `stack`,2. The function that calls `push()`. 1 is necessary to understand how the heap is being corrupted. 2 is necessary to understand why your program has an infinite loop.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<strlen(arr2);i++){` this will copy one byte too few. (possibly it is also inefficient)

Answer (score 1):

You are `free()`ing then accessing the same object when `*head==NULL`.
Look at the lines marked `****` below.

```
if(*head==NULL){
    temp->next = NULL;
    *head = temp;
    tracker = temp;//**** temp is assigned to tracker. They point to the same place.
}
else{
    //...
}

free(temp);     //**** temp is free()d but remember tracker==temp..

//**** Now you output tracker but the object at this location was just freed.
printf("%s %s %f %f ",tracker->date,tracker->year,tracker->pressure,tracker->node_voltage);
```

So remove `free(temp)` it is in the totally wrong place but you haven't given enough code to say where it goes.

The 'indefinite looping' is some other error but you haven't provided enough code to identify that.

Also notice the `else` part doesn't make much sense:

```
    tracker->next = temp;
    tracker = tracker->next;
    tracker->next = NULL;
```

It's not clear what `tracker` is going in but assuming it is valid this amounts to:

```
    tracker = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
```

Comment: This is not the whole answer. Remember that the crash is happening in `free()`. I think something else is corrupting the heap.

Comment: @JeremyP I won't be surprised if it's not the only error. There's a number of issues with this code but that is certainly a fatal problem. They've also assigned the object they `free()` to `*head` which will cause even more trouble later including a possible heap corruption. The code fragment isn't sufficient to actual 'fix' this program.

Comment: Please see the comments above, the issue has been resolved

Comment: @Masquerade The string terminator? The problems with `push()` are still fatal.